# mongodb: update string field to integer

Tags: type-conversion, mongodb-3.6

I have a collection that has some fields that should be integers. Due to a software bug, some of these values are strings. I need to convert them. Here is an example document:

```
var coll = db.getCollection('info');
coll.find({ id: "985517" });
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : "41cbb4e48284c0612a1c4b3ee5e3e2720c01197a",
    "id" : "985517",
    "title" : "009_1a.jpg",
    "ext" : ".jpg",
    "content_type" : "image/jpeg; charset=utf-8",
    "sha1" : "41cbb4e48284c0612a1c4b3ee5e3e2720c01197a",
    "has_thumb" : true,
    "size" : 2917,  
    "width_px" : "70",
    "height_px" : "69"
}
```

I try to convert width_px and height_px values into integers. My first naive try:

```
var coll = db.getCollection('info');
var bulk = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
coll.find({ width_px: { $type: "string" }, id: "985516" }).limit(100).forEach(function(data) {
    var updoc = {
        "$set": {}
    };
    updoc["$set"]["width_px"] = parseInt(data.width_px);
    // queue the update
    bulk.find({
        "_id": data._id
    }).update(updoc);
    counter++;
    // Drain and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
    })
    // Add the rest in the queue
if (counter % 1000 != 0) bulk.execute();
```

The result is dissapointing:

```
{
    "_id" : "41cbb4e48284c0612a1c4b3ee5e3e2720c01197a",
    "id" : "985517",
    "title" : "009_1a.jpg",
    "ext" : ".jpg",
    "content_type" : "image/jpeg; charset=utf-8",
    "sha1" : "41cbb4e48284c0612a1c4b3ee5e3e2720c01197a",
    "has_thumb" : true,
    "size" : 2917,  
    "width_px" : 70.0,
    "height_px" : "69"
}
```

So it was updated to double, instead of int32. I understand that in JavaScript, there is no separate double and integer type, just "number". But I need to update 100 000 documents and I want to do this efficiently.

But how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use NumberInt instead of parseInt.

```
var coll = db.getCollection('info');
var bulk = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
coll.find({ width_px: { $type: "string" }}).forEach(function(data) {
    var updoc = {
        "$set": {}
    };
    updoc["$set"]["width_px"] = NumberInt(data.width_px);
    // queue the update
    bulk.find({
        "_id": data._id
    }).update(updoc);
    counter++;
    // Drain and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
    })
    // Add the rest in the queue
if (counter % 1000 != 0) bulk.execute();
```

It will construct a new NumberInt object that is mongodb specific, and it will be serialized as an int32.

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/documents/) From the `Documents tab` in `MongoDB Compass`, you can view, insert, clone, modify, and delete documents .

First you have to connect your mongod with `MongoDB Compass` then you shall able to change your  desire data type of their respective field in MongoDB.

***Change Field Type***

You can change the data type of a field by using the data type selectors on the right of the field.

[image]

> **Note:** Creating, deleting, editing and cloning documents is not permitted in MongoDB Compass Readonly Edition.

For your further ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/)

Comment: My downvote, because it doesn't answer the question. OP needs a method to update 100k documents in a bulk - that has nothing to do with MongoDBCompass.

Answer (score 0):

change str to int

```
db.db-name.find({field-name: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(obj) { 
obj.field-name = new NumberInt(obj.field-name);
db.db-name.save(obj); });
```